# the way to check which planner is selected

Tags: ros, navigation, base-global-planner, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question has relation to my former question ( http://answers.ros.org/question/152196/about-a-way-to-change-default-global-planner/ ).  I want to confirm which planner is selected. I selected the eband_local_planner and carrot_planner in Rviz and added the definition of eband_local_planner `param name="base_local_planner" value="eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS"`  and  `param name="base_global_planner" value="carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner"`to move_base.launch.xml , but following is displayed on a terminal.

```
ken@ken:~$ rostopic echo /move_base/parameter_descriptions

dflt: 
  bools: 
    - 
      name: recovery_behavior_enabled
      value: True
    - 
      name: clearing_rotation_allowed
      value: True
    - 
      name: shutdown_costmaps
      value: False
    - 
      name: restore_defaults
      value: False
  ints: []
  strs: 
    - 
      name: base_global_planner
      value: navfn/NavfnROS
    - 
      name: base_local_planner
      value: base_local_planner/TrajectoryPlannerROS
```

Could anybody tell me the way to check which planner is selected if I'm wrong?
I think that a dflt means initial value.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152841/the-way-to-check-which-planner-is-selected/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm sorry, it was simple. I can check them with a following topic.

```
ken@ken:~$ rostopic echo /move_base/parameter_updates
bools: 
  - 
    name: recovery_behavior_enabled
    value: True
  - 
    name: clearing_rotation_allowed
    value: True
  - 
    name: shutdown_costmaps
    value: False
  - 
    name: restore_defaults
    value: False
ints: []
strs: 
  - 
    name: base_global_planner
    value: carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner
  - 
    name: base_local_planner
    value: eband_local_planner/EBandPlannerROS
doubles: 
  - 
    name: planner_frequency
    value: 2.0
  - 
    name: controller_frequency
    value: 5.0
  - 
    name: planner_patience
    value: 5.0
  - 
    name: controller_patience
    value: 3.0
  - 
    name: conservative_reset_dist
    value: 3.0
  - 
    name: oscillation_timeout
    value: 10.0
  - 
    name: oscillation_distance
    value: 0.2
groups: 
  - 
    name: Default
    state: True
    id: 0
    parent: 0
---
```

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0